# Selecting a Radio Button Using Selenium and Ruby

Tags: ruby, scripting, selenium, watir, firewatir

Ok, I know this sounds like quite a rudimentary question, and I know there are docs explaining how to do this, however I have not had any luck in doing so.

So say I create my driver in Ruby using Selenium:

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :profile => profile
```

Say I want to click a link, this works just fine with the following syntax:

```
driver.find_element(:class => "button").click
```

However, if I want to select some radio button that is in some table like:

```
<td valign="middle"><input type="radio" NAME="TESTNAME" VALUE="TESTVALUE1"  ></td>
<td valign="middle"><input type="radio" NAME="TESTNAME" VALUE="TESTVALUE2"  ></td>
<td valign="middle"><input type="radio" NAME="TESTNAME" VALUE="TESTVALUE2"  ></td>
```

If I want to check "TESTVALUE2", I cannot seem to do so. For instance the following line:

```
driver.find_element(:name => "TESTNAME").send_keys("TESTVALUE2")
```

So is there some method used for Ruby that I am missing? Can someone provide an example of how to go about doing this? Thanks again.

Comment: What version of firefox?

Comment: What language are you viewing while using Selenium?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why the Watir tag is on this question, but I'm going to respond from that perspective.   If you were using Watir-Webdriver, which combines the webdriver back-end with the Watir API you would do something like this to load the proper gems and create an instance of a firefox browser object

```
require "rubygems"
require "watir-webdriver"
require "watir-webdriver/extensions/wait"

browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
```

Then later once you have navigated to the page, to set a radio button to on, you would use

```
browser.radio(:value, 'TESTVALUE2').set
```

A lot of people coding in Ruby prefer the Watir api since it seems to be considered to be a lot more 'Ruby-esq' than Selenium (which is more Java-esq)

For a more detailed introduction to watir-webdriver, see: http://watirmelon.com/2010/12/14/watir-webdriver-a-detailed-introduction/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a selenium user myself, but I would expect something along the lines of

```
driver.find_element(:name => "TESTNAME", :value => "TESTVALUE2").check
```

to have the desired effect.

Comment: Intuitively, I would think the same thing. However, this yields:  

in `<main>': undefined method `check' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x30fdc50> (NoMethodError)

Comment: Note also that, driver.find_element("SomeLink").click works just fine. So it's not a matter of not having proper installations I would think.

Answer (score -3):

```
driver.find_element(:id, 'TEST_ID').click
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged.